# MySQL multiple where in same column on relational db

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a tables like:

```
pTable_tags:

|  id  |  tag  |  id_pTable
|   1  |  tag1 |      1
|   2  |  tag2 |      1

pTable:

|  id  |  value  |
|   1  |    x    |
```

How can I do a `SELECT` to get the `pTable` value `WHERE tag = tag1 and tag = tag2` at the same time.
note: I can't use an `OR` because it must fulfill both conditions.

Comment: `where` works at the row level. it will NOT scan across rows, so what you want is impossible. a single field in a single record cannot have multiple different values at the same time. so yes, you need `or` (or perhaps an `in`), and the return only the records that fulfill both conditions, e.g. `select count(*) .... having count(*) = 2`.

Comment: @MarcB , I think your comment may be worth posting as an answer, I think that's exactly what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT p1.id, value
FROM pTable AS p1
JOIN pTable_tags AS p2 ON p1.id = p2.id_pTable
WHERE tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
GROUP BY p1.id, value
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(tag)) = 2
```

This assumes `id` is unique in `pTable`. In case `id` is not unique and you want all rows from `pTable` selected, then you can join `pTable` back to a derived table produced by the above query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ceb4/2)